# UITableView deletion of cell with animation? iOS (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've searched around, it seems that most recommendations are to simply      [tableView reloadData].

However, I am after animation on deletion of the cell. If you can imagine a checklist, I add items to the checklist and once the item/task on the checklist (EG: "Get milk from milk bar") is completed I remove the item/task by tapping on it. At which point I want the cell to disappear with animation.

As mentioned above, most people just recommend a route which would involve me removing the item from the array it is held in and simply reloading the tableview, but that's completely void of animation.

Below is what I've tried as an alternative with little success.

```
[tableView beginUpdates]
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates]
```

Note: The taskArray is populated with task's I enter. Additionally, the above code resides within the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method.
Any tips as to what im doing wrong or what I could do instead?

TLDR; I want to remove a cell with animation from the tableView simply by tapping on it.

Comment: As MultiColour Pixel answered, my mistake was in my array. I wasnt providing an array of index paths rather my NSString filled array.

Problem solved! Thankyou!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick observation, the API is requesting that you provide an array of index paths and you only pass the actual item you're wanting for deletion.

What happens if you try:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the entry from the data source as well.

Comment: Yeah, don't forget to delete the entry from your array or whatsoever data source, BEFORE deleting the cell from the table view.

Comment: My god I love you :) PROBLEM SOLVED!

Answer (score 0):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
// Delete from the taskArray
[self.taskArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Remove row from the tableview
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```